# How to Set Telerik RadDatePiker last Selection date range equal Today.Date

Tags: asp.net, html, telerik

I am using telerik raddatepicker, I have Problem that **how to Set Selection end date range qual to today date** in design Side in asp.net

Please give me proper solution that how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code .

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="datEffectiveDate" runat="server" Enabled="true" Width="200px"
MaxDate="<%# DateTime.Today.Date %>">
```

When using a databinding expression such as <%# DateTime.Today.Date %>, then you have to call Page.DataBind() (or ltrDate.DataBind() if that's the only databound control) from your code-behind (e.g. in Page_Load).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.DataBind();
}
```

Hope this helped.